# angular 9: Multiple conditions on ngClass inside a ngFor

Tags: css, angular, ng-class

I'm having some issues trying to print the typical star-rating widget in my page using angular. Probably there will be an easier way to show them using css but for now i wanted to do it by code.

```html
<i *ngFor="let star of this.stars" [ngClass]="{
    'score__star fas fa-star': star === 'full',
    'score__star fas fa-star-half-alt': star === 'half', 
    'score__star far fa-star': star === 'empty'
    }"></i>
```

this is the code of the widget and this is the content of the array of stars:

```
(5) ["full", "full", "half", "empty", "empty"]
```

i'm not sure why, chrome draws properly the first 2 but not the others. From what i have seen in the debugger there are parts of the class that are missed...

```html
<i _ngcontent-lqd-c56="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class=""></i>
<i _ngcontent-lqd-c56="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class=""></i>
<i _ngcontent-lqd-c56="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
<i _ngcontent-lqd-c56="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="score__star far fa-star"></i>
<i _ngcontent-lqd-c56="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="score__star far fa-star"></i>
```

Any idea of what i'm missing? I also tried to mix class and ngClass to split the common part of the style but i had the same problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks okay. Try printing {{star}} inside the i and see what it shows?

Comment: Just tested it, and the texts are ok

Comment: In that case.. I have no idea I’m afraid. Is there anything else in either the component or the template that can affect those classes?

Comment: If i put the items with the style hardcoded in the class attribute it works fine... So i guess not, but i'm not an expert on css even or angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one workaround for this problem.
Could you change your classes, e.g:

```
getClasses(star) {
  return {
    'full' : star === 'full',
    'half' : star === 'half', 
    'empty' : star === 'empty' 
}}
```

Also I'm not sure If you know this but you can pass method to ngClass directive

```
<i *ngFor="let star of stars" [ngClass]="getClasses(star)">
  {{star}}
</i>
```

Comment: Yeah, this worked. I knew i could use a method but completely forgot about it. Thanks!